# How to print the date in iphone?

Tags: iphone, date, format

I am new to iphone development.I am having array of date .I want to print the date in my console.But I didn't want to convert it into a string and print it.I want to print as a date.How can i achieve that.Please help me out thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSDate date]);
```

The `%@` specifier can accept any ObjC objects. It will call `-description` to convert it into a string automatically when printing.